# Date Filtering with the MS Sync Framework

Tags: synchronization, replication, microsoft-sync-framework

After having many disasters with trying to getting merge replication to get work with occasionally connected mobile devices and PDAs using SQL CE we've decided to give the Synchronization framework a go.

We have a scheduling application which has a master SQL 2005 DB which updates SQL CE DBs on multiple mobile devices.  The master scheduling table has a dateoccurs field which is when the event happens and this table can have records for multiple years in it - somewhere around 10s of thousands of records.

Obviously we don't want the mobile apps SQL CEs to have this many records - just the ones a week either side of the current date.  Is there a way to filter the records being transferred using the Sync Framework to the mobile devices?  I can't see any code on how to filter the data based on date anywhere on the M'soft site

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this help:

[Filtering data in ado .net synchornization](http://msmvps.com/blogs/williamryan/archive/2007/11/13/filtering-data-ado-net-synchronization-services.aspx)